# Open JPA - column definition binary

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I'm trying to set the type of a column in OpenJPA as binary(5) so I'm using the following declaration:

```
@Column(name="MY_FIELD", columnDefinition="BINARY(5)")
public byte[] getMyField() {
    return myField;
}
```

However, the column is always created as a blob:

```
| MY_FIELD   | blob         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Any clues on getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in OpenJPA, introduced by [OPENJPA-740](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-740). I've opened a bug report on your behalf: [OPENJPA-1870](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1870).

Answer (score -1):

The [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property) says the @Lob annotation is to be used :

> @Lob indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a Clob depending on the property type:
>   java.sql.Clob, Character[], char[] and java.lang.String will be persisted in a Clob.
>   java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[] and serializable type will be persisted in a Blob.

It works nicely with Hibernate: it should be ok for you with OpenJPA, since the [documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_streamsupport) says @Lob is handled "in a standard JPA manner".

Comment: But persistence as a Blob is exactly what I don't want. I want persistence as a mysql Binary type @see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html